# "What is x?" as a non-question title

Tags: academia

I am working on my PhD thesis. I would like to have section title like "What is *x*"? (Specifically, "What is Information Flow Security?") However, I wish to avoid rhetorical questions in my academic writing, and so I was wondering if there is a way in which I can word this title such that it is not a question. Something like "Defining Information Flow Security" but *not* that, because definitions are something else entirely and I won't be offering a formal definition at this point in the work.

Comment: So this section is "An introduction to Information Flow Security" or something less detailed?

Comment: Is this part of a larger section already called _Information Flow Security_?  If it isn't, then this could be the section title and, in the first sentence of the section, you can outline what you intend to cover in the section.

Comment: @Shoe My working title for the larger section is _The What, Why & How of Information Flow Security_. I did consider _Information Flow Security_ as the heading of the sub-section, but to me it read as a much more broader section title than I am intending.

Comment: Section headings are often introduced by interrogative pronouns without being questions: What IFS constitutes, Why IFS is important, How to implement IFS, etc. I don't have a better word than _constitutes_, but your sub-section titles mirror your main section title if you do it this way.

Comment: "Aspects of Information Flow Security"

Comment: "An overview of Information Flow Security"

Comment: Have you tried asking your advisor? They should be able to advise you on the conventions for academic writing.

Comment: To all who have commented, thank you. When I posted the question I was thinking there might be a 'transformative trick' to move from question to title. Thanks to @Greybeard - I'll forge ahead with _Aspects of Information Flow Security_.